# How do I get the top-level terms in a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom hierarchical taxonomy setup for a conference website. The top-level terms in this taxonomy are Dates, which have child terms representing session slots on that date. I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of the top-level terms within the taxonomy, that is I only want the terms that are Dates, not the terms that are sessions. Is this possible using `get_terms()`?

Answer (score 22):

Try to pass `0` for `parent` argument in [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

> **parent**  *(integer)* Get direct children
>   of this term (only terms who's
>   explicit parent is this value). If 0
>   is passed, only top-level terms are
>   returned. Default is an empty string.

Comment: +1 - This is the answer you're looking for... ;)

Comment: This worked for me! But why doesn't this function have a "depth" argument like other Wordpress get functions?

Comment: @Anatidaus who knows... btw I won't say depth is that common.

Answer (score -1):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms.

Use the hierarchical = 0

```
$my_taxonomy = get_terms('my_taxonomy', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0&hierarchical=0');
```

Comment: nope. `hierarchical=0` doesn't work. The better way is `parent=0`